# Adoble Illustrator: Penrose tiling - Golden aspect ratio

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Can someone help me how to create this tiling? I don't know how it is generated. I know that the creator uses Adobe Illustrator, but I can't imagine how. Maybe the creator import from Nodebox or Mathematica? How this is possible in Illustrator?

Many thanks, guys.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what this has to do with the Golden Ratio, however, if you want an exact pattern to follow, then I think it would be better to colour code and label the tiles.  The pattern on the tiles makes it look more complex than it really is, so perhaps better to simplify these as just tile shapes. This is really a manual job, and there's no way to automate it as far as I know, also there are probably many variations possible for tiling these shapes.

For example:

[image]

I made this in Inkscape, however the same should be possible in Illustrator. Although Inkscape has many more snapping options than Illustrator, which makes snapping these shapes a breeze.

Comment: Really thanks for your time, @Billy Kerr! The work and the explanation is fantastic! I will try that.

Comment: Illustrator in this case has same snapping options its just that illustrator is a bit quirky and you dont get the options unless you use the white arrow tool (instead of black) and really use the rotate **tool**. Also disableing alignment guides helps

Comment: Also obviously you CAN automate this.

Comment: @joojaa How?? Thanks.

Comment: @Maxwell Well there are 2 algorithms for this and countless variation. The other is like humans do it, and the other is subdividing. There are lots of articles on how to do this from L-parser formulas to Matrix transforms. All you need really is to port the code into something that your editor understands. Like i said google has many examples from P1 to P3 You could just use one of those as a startingpoint (though many of these use half tile aporoaches so you would need to merge the results. I would do this but i havent got time (I would need to find a uninterupted 3 hours)

Answer (score 4):

Dont over analyze things. It is very possible that the tiling is just done by hand. Graphic designers are big on such things. After all if you see a penrose tiling on a floor then it was most likely manualy tiled too.

It wouldn't take all that long time to do manually, in my experience about 10-15 minutes (yeah ive done it). Just move and rotate the pieces by their vertices in place, it gets faster over time as you can copy bigger repeating structures. And unless you need the field to be somehow very big you can just do it once, with each kite and each dart being a symbol. Thisway you could just reuse the same template forever with any design you like in the time it takes you to design the kite and dart.

But yeah if you dont want to do that find and penrose generator online that draws svg then save the svg. Open that in illustrator.  Top of [google search here](https://misc.0o0o.org/penrose/).

Comment: Yes, that was done mannually.

Answer (score 0):

This series of videos shows how to create these Penrose Tiles (Darts & Tiles) using Inkscape open-source software:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ru9MrsHaGAk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeSZfd8eu9U
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LaM_cTinAs

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE. This is what we call a "link only answer". When the link dies one day your answer will loose its meaning. This site aims to be the place where you find the answers, not just links to other sites. Please try to explain and illustrate the method instead.